# Need to authenticate InfluxDB which is in Azure Cloud while sending k6 results from local machine

Tags: azure, performance-testing, influxdb, k6

I have k6 scripts on my local Windows 10 machine. I want to write k6 execution results/stats to InfluxDB database which is hosted in Azure cloud server. Execution is working perfectly fine but not able to write stats on InfluxDB database. I am taking following approach to run script

```
    k6 run  --out influxdb=<user>:<password>@http://10.65.202.1:8086/DatabaseName script.js
```

my user = admin

password is = pass@123

InfluxDB database name is = DatabaseName

I have tried following commands -

```
  k6 run --out influxdb=admin:pass%40123@http://10.65.202.1:8086/DatabaseName script.js
  OR
  K6_INFLUXDB_USERNAME=admin K6_INFLUXDB_PASSWORD=pass@123 k6 run --out 
  influxdb=http://10.65.202.1:8086/DatabaseName script.js"
```

Looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error output? Have you run with `--debug` enabled?

Comment: ERRO[0093] Couldn't write stats                          error="Post \"http://localhost:8086/write?consistency=&db=k6&precision=ns&rp=\": dial tcp [::1]:8086: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." output=InfluxDBv1

Comment: "Connection refused" is not something related to credentials, it means that there is nothing listening on this port. Note that the error says "localhost" which does not match the IP from your script.

Comment: IP and port for InfluxDB is correct.

Comment: I tried with latest k6 0.43.1 and it seems like the form `--out influxdb=user:password@http://...` is not working (always tries to connect to localhost). This seems to be a bug! However, using the `K6_INFLUXDB_USERNAME=... k6 run --out influxdb=http://...` form seems to work for me (I don't have influx set up right now, but it hangs, trying to connect to the fake id which I have provided)